# Ошибка с портами при запуске проекта selenium java (Unable to find a free port)

Tags: java, selenium

Запускаю простейший авто тест на java selenium.
В самом тесте ничего интересного, просто нужно открыть хром и перейти на сайт Youtube

При запуске возникает данная проблема с портами

Подскажите в чем может быть причина данной ошибки, интернет бессилен ((

[image: ошибка]

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил сделав переустановку JDK дефект воспроизводился на версии 181
После перехода на версию 333 данной ошибки не наблюдается, selenium работает, код выполняется